# JavaScript doesnt recognize my custom class from typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, reference

So right now I'm simply testing to see if I can create and store some info in a Javascript file using a custom TypeScript class object. Before testing I'm running the command 'tsc courses.ts' followed by 'node app.js' It says its working and running on the port I specified but when I go to the page it break and says there is a reference error when doing 'let aCourse = new CourseObject' CourseObject is not defined.

Any ideas on how I might fix this?

courses.ts

```
class CourseObject {
    courseNumber: number;       
    courseName: string;
    courseDescription: string;
    credits: number;
    preRequisites: string;
    
    constructor(courseNumber: number, courseName: string, courseDescription: string,
                credits: number, preRequisites: string){
        this.courseNumber       = courseNumber;     
        this.courseName         = courseName;
        this.courseDescription  = courseDescription;
        this.credits            = credits;
        this.preRequisites      = preRequisites;
    }
}
```

app.js

```
... omitted for brevity ...

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            
            let courses = [];
            let aCourse = new CourseObject();

... omitted for brevity ...
```

***EDIT FIXED***
ran tsc --init to generatea tsconfig.json file.
module: commonjs and target es2016

then changed code to:
courses.ts

```
export class CourseObject{ ... }
```

and app.js added

```
const CourseObject = require(PATH/courses.js).CourseObject
```

Thanks @CRice for the help!

Comment: Show us how you export the `CourseObject` in the courses file, and also the corresponding import in the `app.js` file.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could import with JavaScript =o !? Would simply doing 'export class CourseObject { ...' in my TypeScript file, and then 'import {CourseObject} from './courses.ts' work then?

Comment: Kinda depends on your tsconfig as well, since the export will be transpiled differently depending on the setting. Can you tell us what is set for the `module` key in your tsconfig?

Comment: Hmm I'm in the root directory with my app.js and courses.ts etc files but I dont see a tsconfig file. That might be an issue; let me do a quick google and see how to get one..   EDIT: ran tsc --init and now have a file. Modules is set to:  "module": "commonjs",

Comment: In that case, yes, add `export class CourseObject` to the courses file. Then, in `app.js`, you should use `require` to do the import since this is a js file and not a ts file. So the corresponding import would be `const CourseObject = require("./path-to-complied-courses/courses.js").CourseObject;`. Let us know if that works (make sure to replace with your actual path).

Comment: Do you mean to simply add the keyword 'export infront of class CourseObject { ... } ? Cause I just tried that and recived the error: 'unexpected token ''export'.

Comment: What is the `target` in your tsconfig?

Comment: "target": es2016,

Comment: Can you confirm that your `require` call is pointing to the _compiled javascript file_, and NOT to the typescript source file?

Comment: Oh woops made a typo in the PATH. Its compiling now! Thank you very much :D

Comment: Glad to help, please feel free to accept Zabon's answer. I have edited to include the details discussed above.

Answer (score 1):

- Export your class:

```js
export class CourseObject {...}
```

---

- When importing into a `.ts` file:

```js
import { CourseObject } from 'path/CourseObject'
```

- Or when importing into a plain `.js` file, use `require`:

```
const CourseObject = require("./path/CourseObject.js").CourseObject
```

Comment: import wont work in .js file But a solution was found